# moving the characters in a text string a specified number of positions

Tags: java, string

I am new in programming and I am trying to write a program that moves the characters in a text string a specified number of positions.

The program must include a method whose inputs will be a text string (type String) and the number of positions (type `int`). The output will be a string with characters shifted.

For example, moving 4 positions:

```
rabbit eats a carrot
it eats a carrotrabb
```

Now I have this partial code. I can erase first characters but I don't know how to put them to the end of this text. How can i make it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter the text: ");
    Scanner cti = new Scanner(System.in);     
    String a = cti.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter number of positions= ");
    int b = cti.nextInt();
    char firstLetter = a.charAt(0);
    b--;
    a = a.substring(b); 
    String m = a + firstLetter ;
    System.out.println("now it is "+ m);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
import java.util.*;
public class JavaApplication5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter the text: ");
       Scanner cti = new Scanner(System.in);     
       String a = cti.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter number of positions= ");
        int b = cti.nextInt();
       String firstPart = a.substring(0,b);   // line 1
       b--;
       a = a.substring(b); 
       String m = a + firstPart ;             // line 2
        System.out.println("now it is "+ m);
    }
    
}
```

See the changes above in statement marked with comment line 1 and line 2.

In line 1, we are getting the first part of string and in line 2, adding at the end of second string part.

Answer (score 2):

If you use regex, it's just one line:

```
return str.replaceAll("^(.{" + n + "})(.*)", "$2$1");
```

Comment: This is the best answer by far.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String foo(String s, int n) {
    String s2 = s.substring(0, n);
    s = s.substring(n) + s2;
    return s;
}
```

you can put a few validations on this, like null string or n is less than s.length() etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use modulus operator to calculate number of shifts. When initial number of shift is more than string length. Check this :

```
public String shift(String string,int n){
    int nshift = string.length() < n ? n%string.length() : n ;
    String a = string.substring(0,nshift);
    return string.substring(nshift) + a ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more version. All the work is essentially done in 1 line here:

```
String result = new StringBuilder(a).delete(0, b).append(a.substring(0,b)).toString();
```

Anyway, the full code is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ShiftLetters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("enter the text: ");
        Scanner cti = new Scanner(System.in);     
        String a = cti.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter number of positions: ");
        int b = cti.nextInt();

        String result = new StringBuilder(a).delete(0, b).append(a.substring(0,b)).toString();

        System.out.println(result);
    }    
}
```

Also, you might want to be more accurate with your indentation style to improve readability.